# Why does this Java code throw a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, swing, parseint

I'm playing around with a GUI Sudoku solver that uses an array of `JTextFields` (`gridArray`) for display and an `int` array (`sudokuGrid`) for the actual solving.  When I run it and it tries to cast the `JTextField` `string`s to `int`s, it throws a `NumberFormatException` on parsing the `string`s into `int`s, specifically this message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Here's the section of code that's causing me trouble:

```
// create solveButton
    solveButton = new JButton("Solve It!");
    solveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                // create grid and call Solve()
                for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
                    for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
                        if (gridArray[i][j].getText() == "")
                            {sudokuGrid[i][j] = 0;}
                        else {sudokuGrid[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(gridArray[i][j].getText());}
                    }
                } // end for loop

                Solver(sudokuGrid);

                // display solution
                for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
                    for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
                        gridArray[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(sudokuGrid[i][j]));
                    }
                } // end for loop
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame,e.toString(),"Number Format Exception",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame,"Sorry, something broke, try again.","Solve Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } // end try-catch
        } // end actionPerformed()
    }); // end solveButton ActionListener
```

I thought that the `if`-`else` would catch the empty fields and only try the `parseInt` if there was a value present, but if anyone can enlighten me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You should accept the answer that did fix your problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
  if (gridArray[i][j].getText() == "")
```

You can't compare strings that way.  Do it this way instead:

```
if (gridArray[i][j].getText().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking string equality using `==`, which is only for reference equality. Perhaps you meant to write:

`gridArray[i][j].getText().equals("")`

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask the TextArea for it's text, since this may be prone to be still in the editing process. Check the underlying document itself.

```
Document document = gridArray[i][j].getDocument();
sudokuGrid[i][j] = document.getLength() == 0 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(document.getText(0, 1);
```

Also... why a JTextArea? Why not a JTextField? You might even combine this with a JSpinner with values from 0 (which is inerpreted as *empty* to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Using `==` -comparison with strings does not mean checking for equality of the text (string contents), but instead equality of the String-objects (testing are they the exact same OBJECT). Use String.equals() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your equality check:

```
gridArray[i][j].getText() == ""
```

This does not do what you're intending. In Java this checks whether the two strings are the same object not whether their values are equal. 
You should use the String.equals() method to evaluate whether the text field is empty.